# Why 'readable' event won´t fire for my ClientRequest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I am testing a small chunk of code on NodeJS that is supposed to create a ClientRequest object and fire three event:

- 'response' event
- 'readable' event
- 'end' event

Here is a chunk of code I am testing:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();
var link = "www.asos.com";

// now that server is running
server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1', function(){
  tryMe();
});

 function tryMe(){
    var options = {
      hostname: link,
      port: 80,
      method: "GET"
    };
    var asosRequest = http.request(options);
    asosRequest.on("response", function(res){
      console.log("response");
    });
    asosRequest.on('readable', function() {
      console.log("readable");
    });
    asosRequest.on('end', function(){
      console.log("Bey!");
    });
    asosRequest.end();
}
```

I cannot figure out why the "readable" and "end" events won´t fire in my case. "response" event works fine and returns correct info and data buffers. Is there something I misunderstand about how data streams work in node?

NEW:
I use node version v7.7.2.
If I try "data" event, it won´t fire either.

NEW p2: After reading NodeJS docs more carefully, I realized that I was calling event on a wrong object, that I had to call them on response object.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the docs, it became clear to me that I was calling the methods on the wrong objects:
 - The 'response' event only fires on http.ClientRequest object, then you have, the response event callback has a parameter "response"  that represents an instance of http.IncomingMessage. That basically was the object that I needed to call the 'data', 'readable' and 'end' events on, as it represents a readable stream.

Here are the links in NodeJs docs:

- http.ClientRequest: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest
- http.IncomingMessage:
  https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage

Now the code works like this and runs:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();
var link = "www.asos.com";

// now that server is running
server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1', function(){
  tryMe();
});

function tryMe(){
   var options = {
      hostname: link,
      port: 80,
      method: "GET"
   };
   var asosRequest = http.request(options);
   asosRequest.on("response", function(res){
      res.on("data", function(data){
      console.log("data");
   });
   res.on("readable", function(){
     console.log("redable");
     res.read();
   });
   res.on("end", function(){
     console.log("end");
   })
   console.log("response");
   console.log(res.statusCode);
   console.log(res.statusMessage);
});

asosRequest.on('end', function(){
  console.log("Bey!");
});

asosRequest.end();
}
```